# How does one search and retrieve encrypted UN/PW sets safely?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography

I am, as an exercise, writing an app that act as a password bank. It should fit within these parameters:
Leave no plaintext trace (ie never save un-encrypted user data);
Securely store full datasets for an undefined amount of UN/PW pairs;
2-factor as a bonus (dreamy feature).

Getting things encrypted is easy enough, but here's where it gets sticky:
should each account object be encrypted and stored in its own file or should they all be stored in one file ie: (facebook.whatever, google.whatever) or accounts.whatever.

Further, and probably more importantly, how would I access these encrypted datasets? The key should not be stored, but rather generated from a password, so... salt the password used to log into the app and hash it to be used as a key/seed prng for key? Or is there some better way to do this?

The problem I'm running into is this: the app should not dump wrongly decrypted data from a bad password, so there must be some way to check the password, but somehow that does not decrease the security of the system.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about [key derivation functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). It's not as simple as salt+hash+prng.

Comment: To some extent yes, I haven't looked that much at the derivation of the key but thinking more of how to verify the password is correct before showing everything.

Comment: If the password is incorrect, the file will either fail to decrypt (invalid padding or somesuch) or you'll get nonsense bytes. If you had a header in the file with some magic string that you're expecting to be intact, then you could tell whether it was successful by checking for that string?

Comment: I am not positive about the security of this, but let's say you keep 3 fields per record for credentials and 1 server-wide salt also.  The first field is a sha512 hash (maybe hashed many times) of the (server salt + user name).  If someone wants to log in, you hash their UN the same way and look for any matching hash.  If you find one, you do a DeriveBytes on that value, the record level salt, and the provided password to see if it matches the "DeriveBytesOnPassword" field for that record.  This way nothing on your server is plain text but legit users can log in easily

Comment: Make sure your server has a random pause of a couple miliseconds on any user name lookup, though, to prevent timing attacks identifying valid user names.